Does NSPACE($n^2$) $=$ DSPACE($n^4$)?
From Savitch's Theorem, we know that NSPACE($n^2$) $\subseteq$ DSPACE($n^4$), but does the other direction hold? As far as I understand all we can say is that DSPACE($n^4$) $\subseteq$ NSPACE($n^4$).

I believe this is unknown. There are a couple of barriers:
First, it is unknown whether Savitch's theorem is optimal. Imagine we could improve the theorem to show
$$\text{NSPACE}(f(n)) \subseteq \text{DSPACE}(f(n)^{1.9}).$$
In this case your proposed equality could not hold, as this would imply $\text{DSPACE}(n^4) \subseteq \text{DSPACE}(n^{3.8})$ which violates the Space Hierarchy Theorem.
Second, the following problem is also open for almost any $f$:
$$\text{NSPACE}(f(n)) \stackrel{?}{=} \text{DSPACE}(f(n)).$$
(For $f(n) = log(n)$ this is the well-known $\text{L} \stackrel{?}{=} \text{NL}$ problem.)
If the equality holds for $f(n) = n^4$ then it cannot be the case that $\text{NSPACE}(n^2) = \text{DSPACE}(n^4)$ as this would imply $\text{NSPACE}(n^2) = \text{NSPACE}(n^4)$, again violating the Space Hierarchy Theorem.
